# Send Object Information from One Controller's ActionResult to another Controller's ActionResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have two Controllers along with two ActionResults. I am trying to send object information from 1st Controller’s ActionResult into 2nd Controller’s ActionResult. So i have sent my object as specified below,

**1st Controller's ActionResult:**

```
public class A : Controller
{
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
      MyClass MyObject = new MyClass() { ID=123,Name=”MyName”, CreatedDate=DateTime.Now};

      return RedirectToAction("Index", "B", MyObject);
    }
```

}

**2nd Controller's ActionResult**

```
public class B : Controller
{
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(MyClass MyObject)//Getting Null here?
    {   
       // Some Code goes here using MyObject
       return View(MyObject) 
    }
 }
```

2nd Controller’s (B) ActionResult (Index) every time getting with null values? How can I get object details of Controller A in Controller B ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can't work because of nature of redirecting - `RedirectToAction` use `GET` operation. 
With `HTTP GET` you can send some parameters in URL, but not objects (as in `POST`).

If you want to send objects via controllers and methods, you can use `TempData`.
Try this:

```
public class A : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
      MyClass MyObject = new MyClass() { ID=123,Name=”MyName”, CreatedDate=DateTime.Now};

      TempData["myobj"] = MyObject;
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "B");
    }
}


public class B : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {   
       MyObject model = TempData["myobj"] as MyObject;
       return View(MyObject);
    }
 }
```